# The built in function in mapquest to get the lat from an address?

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I want to get the lat of an address entered by the user i am using a licensed mapquest. but i dont know the function to do so and i cant find it over the developer network

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MapQuest JavaScript Maps API, you'll want to take a look at the [geocoding section](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.2/geocoding) in the Developer's Guide.  You can use the geocoding methods to send in the user input and receive the latitude/longitude coordinates -- the toolkit will even add the marker to the map for you automatically.  Hope this helps!